# Gem appears to be a reserved word in builder

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, builder

So apparently builder's `method_missing` hack doesn't like the word gem.  I'm trying to create an element called `gem` and I get an error that it tries to load the gem.

```
xml.gem(:name => gem.name, :version => gem.version)
```

Gives me this:

```
#{gem.name} is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
```

Is there a better way to build this object named gem?

Comment: I was able to get this working with manual xml via `xml << %Q{<gem name=#{gem.name} version=#{gem["version"]}/>}` but it is so messy that if anyone has tips, please let me know.